# How to add a button to a chart.js graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

How do I add a button inside a chart.js graph?
I want to create a pie chart with drill down. The drill down effect is actually pretty easy with a chart onClick function. But I want to add a button to go to the top level to the canvas. I do not want to place it outside the canvas
I found a similar example of a different chart library.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown

Comment: Hi, have you tried annotations plugging and then add click events to annotations with chart js ?